# Sensitive data locally, on GitHub, and support CI/CD

Tags: c#, .net, azure, github, cicd

I'm building a WebAPI server in C# using GitHub to store the source code and perform CI/CD, and Azure WebApp, which is where my pipeline deploys the web API server.

Currently, in my current changes, there's the information to connect to my database, therefore address, username, and password: it's pretty easy to understand that I cannot commit the changes since I would let the world knows my sensitive data :)

Thus, the question is: how should I (or if there are multiple ways, which is the best practice given my scenario) handle this? I've made some researches and:

1. Some suggest to use Azure Key Vault or similar services, but I don't see how this can be solved: somewhere in the code there will still be the call to these services, therefore I would still have sensitive data in the code, right?
2. Some suggest to use Environment variables: I think that I can add environment data both in my local machine and in the repository, then create a service that handle this, something like (is more pseudocode, but I think every methods I would use DO exist):

   ```
   public class SecretConsumer
   {
     public string GetSecret(string secretId) 
     {
       if (Environment.IsGitHub())
       {
         return github.secrets[secretId];
       }
       return environment.getVariable(secretId);
     }
   }
   ```

   The problem with this solution is: how the CI/CD is obtained? I mean, I get how my local machine and the tests running in Github would work, but how the deploy of the app would work? Will I need to add the same environment variables in Azure? Therefore, those information will need manually update each time, right?
3. Some suggest to use a configuration file, like the `appsettings.json` file. Inside of it I will put any sensitive data, and then read it using the C# service.
   Then, this file will NOT be pushed in Github, but instead a sort of `appsettings.template.json` will, so that any other collaborator will be able to use it to recreate the `appsettings.json` file.

   What I don't understand with this approach is: how Github tests and how the CI/CD would work? I mean, Github would have NO clue about a working `appsettings.json` file, so if some tests requires those information.. How, exactly?
   Then, for my Azure WebApp.. Again, the appsettings.json would not be in Github, so it couldn't be deploy to my Azure WebApp: how I could do it? Should I manually deploy the single file? is that even possible?

Comment: I use bcrypt plugin for git. all secrets are encrypted in source control

Comment: @MitchWheat I've searched a little on Google, but I can't find anything that I could use. Can you link some resource?

Comment: https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt   https://dev.to/heroku/how-to-manage-your-secrets-with-git-crypt-56ih

Answer (score 2):

> Some suggest to use Azure Key Vault or similar services, but I don't see how this can be solved: somewhere in the code there will still be the call to these services, therefore I would still have sensitive data in the code, right?

Azure Key Vault is the way to go I think. It can store the database connection, including the username and password.

Then, assign a user managed identity or a system managed identity to your Azure Web App and give that identity permission to access the Key Vault. In your code you then connect to the Key Vault using the [managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview), preventing you from having to use any secret in the code.

A complete example of the above scenario can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-dotnet/keyvault-msi-appservice-sample/).

You can also avoid using the Key Vault and directly access the database using a managed identity, if you configure the software en server to allow that. This follows the same steps: assign a managed identity to the web app, and grant the identity access to the database. See [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-msi-sql-database?tabs=windowsclient%2Cef%2Cdotnet).

If your only secret is the connection string to the database, this would be the preferred solution in my opinion as it avoid the need for the Azure Key Vault.

To use managed identities during local development you need to give your develop account the right permissions on the resources, like you did for the managed identities, see [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication-local-development-dev-accounts?tabs=azure-portal%2Csign-in-visual-studio%2Ccommand-line).

Comment: Thank you! I will read the linked resources.. Though, would this grant me access to the secret even from my local machine, AND the tests running in Github pipelines?

Comment: @Jolly, yes, see updated answer, last part,

Comment: Ok thank you, this evening I will read everything. One last question: Azure Key Vault has a cost. Do you know any other solution which can be used completely free?

Comment: @Jolly €0.028/10,000 transactions is hardly the costs. Would that really be an issue?

Comment: anyway, as outlined in my answer you can avoid the key Vault all together if you connect directly to the database using a managed identity

Comment: Well, it's a side project that I'm building for fun/portfolio, so I really don't want to spend anything on it :')